# Trying to manipulate files in c++

Tags: c++, file, stream

When using `<fstream>` library to open and add a stream to an existing file `test.rtf` and I use the following lines:

```
char data[100];

// open a file in write mode.
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("test.rtf");
if (outfile.is_open()) { cout << "file is open" << endl; }

cout << "Writing to the file" << endl;
cout << "Enter your name: ";
cin.getline(data, 100);

// write inputted data into the file.
outfile << data << endl;
```

And when reading it by using ifstream, the lines input are displayed correctly. The problem is the output file is not modified and lines I have added are not saved. The question might sound very stupid but it's a problem I could not resolve.

Comment: Are you sure the file you're writing to is the same one you're looking at afterwards? You say the contents are there if read via ifstream -- by what other method are you independently checking the file contents?

Comment: Basically, I use ifstream class and file_name >> data to read the contents

Answer (score 3):

When you << to your file you are just writing to a buffer, not actually "flushing" it to the file itself.  If you just close your file you should be fine.

So:

```
outfile.close()
```

Also in the future you can flush (actually write from buffer to the file) when you want to write to a file but not close it.  .close() flushes then closes for you automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I did not include that in my question but I actually did close it as you mentioned, here are the next few lines:                                                      cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> data;
    cin.ignore();
    
    // again write inputted data into the file.
    outfile << data << endl;
    
    // close the opened file.
    outfile.close();

Comment: That should work then, I just built and ran it to verify just in case.  I would follow Cameron's suggestion and double check that you are checking the right file.  Specifically before running your program delete the "test.rtf" that you are checking and make sure it is remade after running your program.  And/or use an absolute directory eg ~/usr/blahblah/test.rtf.

Comment: Thanks! If I am not specifying the directory, where would the file appear?

Comment: No problem, and have fun!  When you use relative links it defaults to the current working directory.  It's generally better to specify an absolute path to avoid confusion.